# Unable to change pathBuff/path variable in async function

Tags: asynchronous, rust, path, borrow

I was unsure if I should post this here or in code review.
Code review seems to have only functioning code.

So I've a multitude of problems I don't really understand.
(I’m a noob) full code can be found here: https://github.com/NicTanghe/winder/blob/main/src/main.rs
main problem is here:

```rust
let temp = location_loc1.parent().unwrap();
location_loc1.push(&temp);
```

I’ve tried various things to get around problems with borrowing as mutable or as reference,
and I can’t seem to get it to work.

I just get a different set of errors with everything I try.
Furthermore, I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but looking for separate solutions to the errors just gave me a different error. In a circle.

Full function

```
async fn print_events(mut selector_loc1:i8, location_loc1: PathBuf) {
    let mut reader = EventStream::new();

    loop {
        //let delay = Delay::new(Duration::from_millis(1_000)).fuse();
        let mut event = reader.next().fuse();

        select! {
            // _ = delay => {
            //      print!("{esc}[2J{esc}[1;1H{}", esc = 27 as char,); 
                 
            // },
            maybe_event = event => {
                match maybe_event {
                    Some(Ok(event)) => {
                        //println!("Event::{:?}\r", event);
                        
                        // if event == Event::Mouse(MouseEvent::Up("Left").into()) {
                        //     println!("Cursor position: {:?}\r", position());
                        // }   
                        print!("{esc}[2J{esc}[1;1H{}", esc = 27 as char,); 
                        if event == Event::Key(KeyCode::Char('k').into()) {
                            if selector_loc1 > 0 {
                                selector_loc1 -= 1;
                            };
                            //println!("go down");
                            //println!("{}",selected)

                        }   else if event == Event::Key(KeyCode::Char('j').into()) {
                            selector_loc1 += 1;
                            //println!("go up");
                            //println!("{}",selected)
                        }   else if event == Event::Key(KeyCode::Char('h').into()) {


                        //-----------------------------------------
                        //-------------BackLogic-------------------
                        //-----------------------------------------
                            let temp = location_loc1.parent().unwrap();
                            location_loc1.push(&temp);
                            
                        //------------------------------------------
                        //------------------------------------------

                        }   else if event == Event::Key(KeyCode::Char('l').into()) {
                            //go to next dir

                        }   if event == Event::Key(KeyCode::Esc.into()) {
                            break;
                        }

                        printtype(location_loc1,selector_loc1);

                    }
                    Some(Err(e)) => println!("Error: {:?}\r", e),
                    None => break,
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

also, it seems using

```
use async_std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
```

makes the rust not recognize unwrap() function → how would I use using ?

Comment: Your `PathBuf` is immutable. It needs to be `mut` in order to change it

Comment: Your github repo compiles just fine

Comment: It seems that i did something wrong trying to push. and the github repo is out of date.

Comment: its up 2 date now

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1. Your `PathBuf` is immutable. It's not possible to modify immutable objects, unless they support [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html). `PathBuf` does not. Therefore you have to make your variable mutable. You can either add `mut` in front of it like that:

```rust
async fn print_events(mut selector_loc1:i8, mut location_loc1: PathBuf) {
```

Or you can re-bind it:

```rust
let mut location_loc1 = location_loc1;
```

2. You cannot have borrow it both mutable and immutably - [the mutable borrows are exclusive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references)! Given that the method `.parent()` borrows the buffer, you have to create a temporary owned value:

```
// the PathBuf instance
let mut path = PathBuf::from("root/parent/child");

// notice the .map(|p| p.to_owned()) method - it helps us avoid the immutable borrow
let parent = path.parent().map(|p| p.to_owned()).unwrap();

// now it's fine to modify it, as it's not borrowed
path.push(parent);
```

Your second question:

> also, it seems using `use async_std::path::{Path, PathBuf};` makes the rust not recognize unwrap() function → how would I use using ?

The async-std version is just a wrapper over std's `PathBuf`. It just delegates to the standard implementation, so it should not behave differently

```rust
// copied from async-std's PathBuf implementation
pub struct PathBuf {
    inner: std::path::PathBuf,
}
```

Comment: Do you know of anny place that explains what 
`.map(|p| p.to_owned())` ?

Comment: I stil get the error.
```move occurs because `location_loc1` has type `std::path::PathBuf`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait```

Comment: @NicTanghe at which line. Please provide a [playground linlk](https://play.rust-lang.org/) that reproduces the issue

Comment: @NicTanghe It works fine with some modification. Here you are: https://pastebin.com/H5YCkH5c You have not made the `location_loc1` mutable as I have already explained above. Also you have to use references instead of moving the value in your `printtype` function